# How to push to multiple Git repositories using multiple accounts on the same machine?

Tags: git

Everything works for the first user (Git user, not Unix user), let's call him aaa, against the first repository.  aaa is set as git user.name and user.email globally using the command

```
git config --global user.name "aaa"
git config --global user.email aaa@live.com
```

aaa executes the command

```
git push origin master
```

successfully.

Then I have a second user, let's call him bbb (again Git user, not Unix usr) on the same machine, but different local working directory, trying to push to a different Git repository.  First, I override the user.name and user.email properties.  So right after git init, I execute:

```
git config user.name "bbb"
git config user.email bbb@live.com
```

Then to confirm:

```
git config --get user.name
```

does return bbb.  When I try to have bbb push to his own repository, git prompts for the SSH passphrase, and it seems to accept the passphrase, but errors out by saying permission denied to aaa.

I suspect that this has something to do with SSH keys.  Is that a right assumption?

Comment: What does the user section of the .git/config file look like?

Comment: Have you figured this one out? I'm not sure I understand why you do a git config on a "git init", and not on a "git clone". Can you also provide the "git clone" commands. If they are local, there should be no reasons to ask for ssh passphrase.

Answer (score 4):

The configured username used for the commit entry in the history, but not for the ssh connection. If you want that to use another username than the one you're logged in with you have to modify the respective `.git/config`'s origin url. I guess `url = ssh://bbb@server/...` might do. If you want a password-free login, you'll have to setup a sshkey for aaa to login as bbb on the server, or use something like gitolite or gitosis.

Answer (score 0):

On a ssh protocol, you shouldn't have to enter the ssh passphrase:
a "`ssh username@servername`" should give you access to the remote (secure) shell.

A permission denied means there is some encapsulation (ssh-based) around your server, like a [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).
The only way gitolite will take `bbb` for `aaa` is if `bbb` used the public key (and access to the private key) of `aaa`, which could be the case if its `$HOME` is somehow the same than `aaa`.